# How to add a control button for displaying data prev entered

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a small screen program which displays patients at the top there is a search button where u can enter by name. I need this search display to be controlled by a button that is, it should not display any records (prev entered) unless click on this button, how would i set this up?

```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Background="LightGray" >


    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" ></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="First Name:" Margin="3"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="sTxtFirstName" Margin="3"></TextBox>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Last Name:" Margin="3"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="3" x:Name="sTxtLastName" Margin="3"></TextBox>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="Gender:" Margin="3"></TextBlock>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="5" x:Name="sCombGender" Margin="3">
            <ComboBoxItem Content=""></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Male"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Female"></ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button x:Name="btnSearch" Grid.Column="6" Margin="3" Height="30" Command="{Binding CMDSearch}" >
            <Button.Content>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/PBM;component/Resources/Images/search.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,2,0" ></Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="Search" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
```

Comment: I think if you vote down a question, you should say why.  What is wrong with this question, other than it's the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going about it all wrong.  Only use grid for laying out controls on the screen.
Use a ListBox to show a list of items.
Declare your items in an ObservableCollection.
Use data binding to bind the listbox to the observable collection.
Use C# to manipulate the contents of the list in response to your button click, then the list data appears automatically.